# podman remote is building only remote dockerfiles

Tags: podman

This is sort of a weird question. But, I can't find any information about this anywhere.

Does podman remote build Dockerfiles from my localhost.

```
podman.exe build --tag mytest:test -f .
```

This is supposed to build a Dockerfile situated in my localhost current directory. Atleast that is how I though it would work. But this is building a Dockerfile in the remote server home directory.

Is this how it is supposed to work, or, is there anyway podman can build a Dockerfile from localhost.

Comment: What do you mean by "remote server"?

Comment: The remote server is a linux server where the actual podman is installed. In my windows laptop I just installed the podman commands and tried to connect podman from my laptop to the remote linux server.

Comment: I believe that is the intended behaviour then. Search for "remote" on this docs page https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-build.1.html